# take images from video stream

Tags: php, image, video, webcam

I want to take images from an (external) video stream. I have no acces to the webcam. Until now, i did this with screenshots. How could I automate this? Would it be possible to get this image directly to my server, using a php-Script? (Without having to switched on my computer all the time and access the website, where the stream is shown [here](http://cam-01.doldernetwork.ch/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=4CIF&clock=1&date=1&text=1&textstring=www.doldersports.com&dummy=1392297253126))

I would know how to do (with php), when the webcam would deliver a single image, but with this cgi-Script I don't know how to deal with from external)

Thanks and regards

Adriana

Answer (score 0):

If you are set on using PHP I would look into [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/). It can do most anything with video sources.

If you are flexible about language you could use a library like [xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) to achieve what you want also.